# ASP.net MVC: Identity and drop auth cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

i never use Identity. so reading a article on it http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

### this is sign in code

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
       user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
       new AuthenticationProperties() { 
          IsPersistent = isPersistent 
       }, identity);
}
```

just do not understand which code in the above lines of code drop auth cookie? please tell me.

when we are working with identity then how to drop auth cookie which will persist in user pc for next 1 or 2 months. just tell me how could i set auth cookie expiration time. please guide. thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "drop"? Do you mean create the cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the expiration time of Cookie when you are configuring the authentication at startup.

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
         ConfigureAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {

        // This uses cookie to store information for the signed in user
        var authOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString(Constants.Paths.LoginPath), //Replace
            LogoutPath = new PathString(Constants.Paths.LogoutPath), //Replace
            //This sets the expiration of the cookie
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(60),   
        };            
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(authOptions);                      
    }
}
```